# Set MicrosoftTeams notification on Prometheus Alertmanager

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, microsoft-teams, prometheus-alertmanager

I try to set Microsoft Teams notifications for Prometheus Alertmanager, but the notification doesn't arrive.

The alertmanager.yaml file is:

```
global:
resolve_timeout: 5m
  http_config: {}
  smtp_hello: localhost
  smtp_require_tls: true
  pagerduty_url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
  hipchat_api_url: https://api.hipchat.com/
  opsgenie_api_url: https://api.opsgenie.com/
  wechat_api_url: https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/
  victorops_api_url: https://alert.victorops.com/integrations/generic/20131114/alert/
route:
  receiver: teams
  group_by:
  - alertname
  routes:
  - receiver: teams
    match:
      alertname: QuotaCPUSolrExcedeed
receivers:
- name: teams
  webhook_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    http_config: {}
    url: https://outlook.office.com/webhook/xxx
templates: []
```

The rule 'QuotaCPUSolrExcedeed' exist and work on Prometheus.

If I put the webhook_url on Grafana, the notification arrives, but if I use alertmanager, no!

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Check this project https://github.com/bzon/prometheus-msteams

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus AlertManager web hook is a [generic one](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#webhook_config). In order to transform the message into format, which is accepted by MS teams, you need to use side car. One of the option [prom2teams](https://github.com/idealista/prom2teams), as it is described in the official [doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#alertmanager-webhook-receiver).

Comment: Thank you! Finally I used the smtp setting for emails